# How to remove the 'Add html button' button from the formatting toolbar

Tags: control-panel, custom-fields

If you show/allow the default HTML formatting buttons for a custom field there is a red cross that allows you to add HTML formatting buttons.

Many of my users find this confusing and don't understand what is on offer or how to do it, so I'd like to be able to remove it.

Ideally I'd rather not have to hack a core file, but if that's the only way to do it which file contains the means?

Comment: What kind of field are you talking about? I can't replicate this "red cross" with either an XHTML Textarea with all options enabled, nor with a Rich Text field.

Comment: @Derek check that "Display Rich Formatting Buttons" is set to "yes" in that Channel's Preferences. Could be why you don't see it. Or did you figure out a different way to hide it?

Comment: Learning something every day. Never saw those before. Using constrained versions of Wygwam, Redactee, Editor or NSM TinyMce (free) for all projects for so long.

Comment: Alex has got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This red cross?

[image]

As far as I can tell the only way to remove this without hacking the core is to use [override.css](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_styles/index.html#overriding-control-panel-style) or to add a CSS snippet to the control panel (use [CP CSS & JS)](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js).

```
.markItUpHeader .btn_plus {
    display: none;
}
```